# iOS 9.1- iPad Pro - UIWebview viewport issue

Tags: ios, html, ipad, mobile-safari, viewport

I am having issues with html5 meta viewport tag on iPad Pro only. I have created a page with like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024,user-scalable=no" />
     </head>
     <body>
               //Some tags here
     </body>
</html>
```

When i view this page using UIWebView in my app, page is not rendered end to end. Total page width is "1366px" and my content is displyed in 1024px. So delta = 1366 - 1024 px white space. User agent here is "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13B137".

But when I view the same page in safari, it is rendered correctly with page width equals "1024px" as specified in meta tag. Hence no white space.
This issue is specific to iPad Pro only. Rest of the variants are working fine. User agent here is : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B137 Safari/601.1".

Can somebody please help me out? This is very urget for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow @ASingh, I just created a ticket at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950251/ios-9-safari-viewport-bug I posted an image. Have I replicated your issue on iOS 9.0 - 9.2 iPad Air?