# iOS 9 Safari Viewport bug

Tags: ios, ipad, viewport, meta-tags

I'm working on the iPad version of a web project and am using Safari's web inspector to work with CSS layout etc. However I've tracked my bug to the viewport meta tag.

When an iPad Air with iOS 9.0 - 9.2 is in portrait mode the viewport meta rules are broken/ignored. Here is a screenshot of the issue from an iPad air iOS 9.2:

[image]

**The Problem:**
When in portrait the computed width for the `html` and `body` tag is 768px yet there is a white space to the right that is about 300px. Also `user-scalable=no` does not apply. Fixed items like the nav and footer appear as 100% as seen in the image.
Landscape is fine and all other devices / OS' are working as expected.

The website is Utilidata.com. Has anyone seen this behavior or know of a fix?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

UPDATE: I'm seeing [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/3la04p/psa_safari_on_ios9_has_a_media_query_bug/) people freaking out about iOS 9's viewport issues. However their `shrink-to-fit=no` solution doesn't fix.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to incorporate below changes to `meta` > `viewport`:

- Remove `width=device-width` and `height=device-height`
- Also set
  *-scale to `1.0001` from `1.0`.

-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0001, minimum-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Worked well for me! Good Luck!!!