# Responsive web page shrinking to fit entire page on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design, frontend

I've made a mobile version of a webpage and it works on Android and small browser windows without problems. 
On iOS however, when a user pinches the screen, it zooms out to fit the entire page on the screen. It's a long page, so this is not ideal.

I have the following in my head:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
     initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

I'm aware that iOS 10 has a known issue with overriding user-scalable=no, but this is happening also on iOS 9 and 8.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might be able to solve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is old but it's one of the few pages that comes up in search for this issue. You don't have to disable zooming to fix this issue. The below viewport tag prevented the whole page from showing in the viewport when pinching the site but retained the ability for users to zoom in and back out.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct format of that `meta` tag is as follows:

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,width=device-width" name="viewport">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, its not a fix for the problem.

Comment: Strange, I've never come across (or, at least, been made aware of) any issues using the above. Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36304667/4768433) any use to you?

Comment: Do not use `user-scalable=0`!!! This prevents users from zooming in and out, so those with less than ideal eyesight may not be able to read the content. There is no reason for it, except maybe for very rare cases like web games. See also http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho.